# Need to construct object back from db tables using ODB orm tool

Tags: orm, odb

I need to use ODB to make the C++ objects persistent. I know with ODB we can generate the .sql file ad then map it into respective database; however can we do the reverse thing using ODB ? as in constructing the objects back from db tables ?

Any help on this would be much appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

Best I can tell there is no way to do this using ODB.  It does not seem to have any tooling to go in this direction.  Although I did find some interest in this from earlier this year.

http://www.codesynthesis.com/pipermail/odb-users/2014-February/001775.html

You can keep your fingers crossed until then!